# Pentaho and dropbox integration

Tags: pentaho, dropbox, dropbox-api

I am new to Pentaho. I want to download a dropbox folder containing multiple files using pentaho, merge those files and use in other steps of integration.

I have already created a Dropbox API, have API key, access token etc. I previously integrated this in JAVA but as required by my company I need to convert all my data extraction code to Pentaho.

How do I achieve this? Please help.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: yes, you can use get files with ftp or sftp step in job. or if you done in java then you can use user defined java class to download files.

Comment: If you have an API, depending on how it's built, you can fully access it through pentaho, either through tailored HTTP POST/GET calls.